# Linking $PATH with mySQL

Tags: mysql, macos, bash, unix, terminal

I'm having trouble getting mysql commands to work because, for some reason, it can't find the directory to the mysql files even though the path listed is correct.

Here is what I get when I enter $PATH:

-bash: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin: No such file or directory

However, I can CD into that path, and the files are listed there. How come they cannot be found?

Thanks

Comment: As a temporary fix, you can execute the command by using the full file path to the binary, in this case, `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -uroot -p` would suffice.

Comment: I tried that, but unfortunately it returns an error:   ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: That likely means that the mysql service is not running, if you are root, and this is a linux distribution go ahead and type `/etc/init.d/mysqld start` and try again.

Comment: `$PATH` is not a command but a variable with different paths concatenated. A file in /usr/local/mysql/bin should be found with the given $PATH.

Comment: What do you mean "the commands cannot be found"? What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: How did you install mysql?